# Что выполняют CallAdapterFactory в Retrofit?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, rxjava2

.addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С помощью метода `addCallAdapterFactory` вы расширяете ваш retrofit сторонними библиотеками. В данном случае вы добавляете поддержку RxJava 2. Список доступных адаптеров [тут](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-adapters).